# How create legend for bubble chart in d3? Legend not showing up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, legend, bubble-chart

My aim is to add a legend to [Clustered Bubble Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/ctufts/f38ef0187f98c537d791d24fda4a6ef9) based on the color of a cluster. The way that I did has no results.

In my CSV file, I created 5 clustered with different colors. In fact, I want to differentiate each cluster by name and color.

The code does not have any errors but nothing showing up. Can someone take look at it and tell what is wrong with it? Do you have any other suggestions to add a legend to the bubble chart?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
circle {
    stroke: #565352;
    stroke-width: 1;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 1000,
    height = 1000,
    padding = 1.5, // separation between same-color nodes
    clusterPadding = 6, // separation between different-color nodes
    maxRadius = 65;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(["#5499C7", "#8E44AD", "#138D75", "#F1C40F", "#D35400"]);

d3.text("word_groups.csv", function(error, text) {

  var legendRectSize = 18;
  var legendSpacing = 4;
  if (error) throw error;
  var colNames = "text,size,group\n" + text;
  var data = d3.csv.parse(colNames);

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.size = +d.size;
  });

//unique cluster/group id's
var cs = [];
data.forEach(function(d){
        if(!cs.contains(d.group)) {
            cs.push(d.group);
        }
});

var n = data.length, // total number of nodes
    m = cs.length; // number of distinct clusters

//create clusters and nodes
var clusters = new Array(m);
var nodes = [];
for (var i = 0; i<n; i++){
    nodes.push(create_nodes(data,i));
}

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height])
    .gravity(.02)
    .charge(0)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g").call(force.drag);

var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
    var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
    var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
    var vert = i * height - offset;
        return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
    });

    legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
    .style('fill', color)
    .style('stroke', color);

    legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function(d) { return "Hans"; });

node.append("circle")
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.cluster);
    })
    .attr("r", function(d){return d.radius})


node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.text.substring(0, d.radius / 3); });

function create_nodes(data,node_counter) {
  var i = cs.indexOf(data[node_counter].group),
      r = Math.sqrt((i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random())) * maxRadius,
      d = {
        cluster: i,
        radius: data[node_counter].size*1.5,
        text: data[node_counter].text,
        x: Math.cos(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + width / 2 + Math.random(),
        y: Math.sin(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + height / 2 + Math.random()
      };
  if (!clusters[i] || (r > clusters[i].radius)) clusters[i] = d;
  return d;
};

function tick(e) {
    node.each(cluster(10 * e.alpha * e.alpha))
        .each(collide(.5))
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var k = "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        return k;
    })

}
// Move d to be adjacent to the cluster node.
function cluster(alpha) {
    return function (d) {
        var cluster = clusters[d.cluster];
        if (cluster === d) return;
        var x = d.x - cluster.x,
            y = d.y - cluster.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = d.radius + cluster.radius;
        if (l != r) {
            l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
            d.x -= x *= l;
            d.y -= y *= l;
            cluster.x += x;
            cluster.y += y;
        }
    };
}
// Resolves collisions between d and all other circles.
function collide(alpha) {
    var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
    return function (d) {
        var r = d.radius + maxRadius + Math.max(padding, clusterPadding),
            nx1 = d.x - r,
            nx2 = d.x + r,
            ny1 = d.y - r,
            ny2 = d.y + r;
        quadtree.visit(function (quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                    y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                    l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                    r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.cluster === quad.point.cluster ? padding : clusterPadding);
                if (l < r) {
                    l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
                    d.x -= x *= l;
                    d.y -= y *= l;
                    quad.point.x += x;
                    quad.point.y += y;
                }
            }
            return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
        });
    };
}
});

Array.prototype.contains = function(v) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === v) return true;
    }
    return false;
};

</script>
```

Comment: could you detail what is contained within the word_groups.csv file? Since I wanted to make a jsfiddle out of it to reproduce the problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/7eda9rt4/

Comment: @N.Schipper 
Here is the [link](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/11b17d52f1d7a7fc01ea93e4f9b724af/word_groups.csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `color.domain` array is empty when you join it with the .legend selection, so no 'g' elements are appended.

The `color.domain` array is populated later in your code, when you append the circles to your nodes selection.

If you switch the order, then the legend items are created:

```
var node = svg
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
      .call(force.drag)

////MOVED BEFORE THE LEGEND CODE
node
  .append('circle')
  .style('fill', function (d) {
    return color(d.cluster)
  })
  .attr('r', function (d) {
    return d.radius
  })

var legend = svg
  .selectAll('.legend')
  .data(color.domain())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
    var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing
    var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2
    var horz = -2 * legendRectSize
    var vert = i * height - offset
    return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')'
  })

legend
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', legendRectSize)
  .attr('height', legendRectSize)
  .style('fill', color)
  .style('stroke', color)

legend
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
  .text(function (d) {
    return 'Hans'
  })
```

*PS: Some of the legend items are currently being translated off the SVG view, so your `horz` and `vert` variables need looking at.*